# Datatables: How can i set cell selector?

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, datatables

I am working on a MVC application that is using datatables  (https://datatables.net/)

I want to show "Approve" button in the last column if column values of PayableAmount and InvoiceAmount are equal. But if they are un-equal "Details" button should be shown

I know i can use ternary operator in defaultContent for button's column to make the desicion but i am not able to get individual cell's value for the 2 columns.

Found this article : https://datatables.net/reference/type/cell-selector
but dont know how to set/use the cell-selectors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `render` function on the `columns` array for your final cell like this:

```
var example = $("#example").DataTable({
    "columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null, {
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                if (numeral(row[1]) > numeral(row[2])) {
                    return $("<button></button>", {
                        "text": "Details"
                    }).prop("outerHTML")
                } else {
                    return $("<button></button>", {
                        "text": "Approve"
                    }).prop("outerHTML")
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

It should do something like what you need. A working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/4wL1vqfz/). Basically the third variable passed to the render function is the whole `row` and in this example I'm using [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) to parse the currency formatted numbers, comparing them and returning a HTML string depending upon whether the Billed amount is greater than the Paid amount.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works perfectly fine ! (y)
Its even better than the solution i had found :D

Comment: In case, any one else wants to get the cell value then this is a way around the problem:-

var table = $('#SupplierInvoice').DataTable();
 var rows = table.rows().data();
if(rows != null && rows.length > 0 )
                    {
                        for(var rowNo = 0 ; rowNo < rows.length ; rowNo++)
                        {
                            var creditAmount = table.cell(table.row(rowNo).index(),16).data();
                            var status = table.cell(table.row(rowNo).index(),29).data();
}
}
here, 16 and 29 are the column numbers.remember to include invisible cols! :)